# Grid Search Hyperparameter tuning,No of searches made when there is one parameter with 2 choices?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, grid-search

Im performing parameter tuning.

```
classifier=KerasClassifier(build_fn=getModel,epochs=10,batch_size=32)

parameters={'activation':['softmax','sigmoid']}

a=GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,cv=10,param_grid=parameters)

results=a.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(results.best_score_)
print(results.best_params_)
```

Shouldnt it run twice 10 epoches with the first one with softmax and the second one with sigmoid as the activation function?
But its running more than 2 times.

Comment: How many times does it run? Could you please post your whole code, e.g. where you call `fit` ?

Comment: You forget the `cv=10` argument in `GridSearchCV`!

Comment: Add `verbose=3` in your `GridSearchCV` like this:`a=GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,cv=10,param_grid=parameters, verbose=3)` and try again.

Comment: @desertnaut  got it.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about cross validation.
Even that was being printed during execution which i got confused to actual grid search.